how to create daily log files from a single mongod.log file?
I am a PostgreSQL user and in Postgres, a daily log is been generated so that also we can decide what we want to log, but in MongoDB, there is only a single mongod.log file Requesting to suggest to me [1] How I can generate an everyday log file. [2] decide what should I log in to log files in the MongoDB community edition.

Regarding daily logfile: Use logrotate tool. Execute it daily by cron job.
The logrotate config file could be like this one:
missingok
compress
delaycompress
notifempty
create    

/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log{
  size 10M
  rotate 9
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    if /usr/sbin/pidof -s mongod > /dev/null ; then kill -USR1 $( /usr/sbin/pidof mongod ) ; fi
  endscript
}

The MongoDB logging behavior you can control with systemLog settings.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Either use systemLog.verbosity where you can set level of verbosity from 0 to 5 or use systemLog.component to set it more granular.
